# sql oracle query para restar dos campos

Tags: sql, oracle

Buenas, he puesto las querys originales que voy a usar para que os hagais idea del problema real, yo necesito restar los valores que devuelven estas dos querys y hacerlo todo en una misma query, es decir, en una misma query recuperar ambos valores y luego en la misma query restarlas.
una query sería:

```
select count(*)  from ( select rownum  rnum from all_objects where rownum <= last_day(to_date('29/07/2016','dd/mm/yyyy')) - to_date('29/07/2016','dd/mm/yyyy')+1 )
where to_char( to_date('29/07/2016','dd/mm/yyyy') +rnum-1, 'DY' ) not in ( 'SAT', 'SUN' )
```

y otra sería:

```
select count(*) from T0GCDFES where trunc(fhdiafes)<=trunc(LAST_DAY(to_date('16/11/2016','dd/mm/yyyy')))
and trunc(fhdiafes)>=to_date('16/11/2016','dd/mm/yyyy') and cdcalend='CIG'
```

quiero en una sola query sql oracle restar los dos valores que me devuelven ambas consultas, es decir tipo `(query1)-(query2)`.

Las querys exactas son esas,perdonar que no haya podido ponerlas hasta ahora, esas dos querys me devuelven cada una un valor, por ejemplo la primera query me devuelve :

```
dias_laborables : 8
```

y la segunda :

```
dias_festivos: 2
```

quiero una query que me devuelva la resta de `8 - 2 = 6`, pero necesito que en una sola query haga las dos querys que pongo y la resta de los dos campos que me devuelve, no se si me explico

Comment: No entiendo. ¿Puedes dar ejemplos concretos de los datos y del resultado deseado?

Comment: Lo que pides no tiene sentido. Por favor incluye un ejemplo de los datos que habría en una tabla, en la otra y la salida que esperas.

Answer (score 4):

Dado que, según se deduce de tu pregunta

- ambas tablas tienen un solo registro
- ambos campos son numéricos

Puedes realizar la resta directamente así:

```
select a.dias_laborables - b.dias_festivos resultado
  from TABLADIAS a
       cross join TABLADIFE b
```

Comment: De acuerdo a la descripción actual de la pregunta, esta es la respuesta correcta. No sé para qué alguien le dio un voto negativo.

Comment: @sstan, parece que se el _downvoter_ se arrepintió.... :o

Comment: se lo perdonamos :)

Comment: aunque no se hubiese arrepentido, uno de pronto se acostumbra al _hater_ eventual... :D :D :D

Comment: yo vote negativo, pensando en que bastaba con lo que habia dejado yo como respuesta (asumiendo que era sql server no era necesario ni un join ni menos el from) luego cuando me corregiste vote a favor porque tu respuesta era la correcta y borre la mia. Saludos!

Comment: @sioesi, la respuesta presentaba otro enfoque desde el inicio. Me alegra que cambiaras tu opinión, pero como ya he dicho, tampoco me lo tomo personal. Es normal también cometer algún error, sobre todo cuando la pregunta es sujeta a cierta interpretación. Yo mismo acabo de corregir una pregunta de la que ignoré, sin querer, una etiqueta. Son gajes del oficio de intentar ayudar. Me parece digno de admirar que salieras al paso para aclarar lo del voto negativo. Un saludo cordial.

Comment: Es sumamente importante que ambas tablas tengan un solo registro.  Un cross join de dos tablas grandes resulta en el producto del tamaño de las dos tablas.  Si ambas tablas contienen mil registros, se tiene que hacer un millón de contrastes.